# Grouping and Summing Totals in a Joined Table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables Medication and Inventory. I'm trying to SELECT all the below details from both tables but there are multiple listings of medication ids with different BRANCH_NO also in the INVENTORY table (the primary key in INVENTORY is actually BRANCH_NO, MEDICATION_ID composite key)

I need to total up the various medication_IDs and also join the tables in one SELECT command and display all the infomation for each med (there are 5) with a total sum of each med at the end of each row. But im getting all muddled trying Group by and Sum and at one point partition. Help please I'm new to this.

Below is the latest non working version - but it doesn't display

- Medication Name
- Medication Desc
- Manufacturer
- Pack Size

like i chanced it might.

```
SELECT I.MEDICATION_ID,
SUM(I.STOCK_LEVEL)
FROM INVENTORY I
INNER JOIN (SELECT MEDICATION_NAME, SUBSTR(MEDICATION_DESC,1,20) "Medication Description",
MANUFACTURER, PACK_SIZE FROM MEDICATION) M ON MEDICATION_ID=I.MEDICATION_ID
GROUP BY I.MEDICATION_ID;

For the data imagine I want this sort of output:

MEDICATION_ID        MEDICATION_NAME       STOCK_LEVEL      OtherColumns.....
1                    Alpha                 10
2                    Bravo                 20
3                    Charlie               20
1                    Alpha                 30
4                    Delta                 10
5                    Echo                  20
5                    Echo                  40
2                    Bravo                 10

grouping and totalling into this:

MEDICATION_ID        MEDICATION_NAME       STOCK_LEVEL      OtherColumns.....
1                    Alpha                 40
2                    Bravo                 30
3                    Charlie               20
4                    Delta                 10
5                    Echo                  60
```

I can get this when its just one table but when Im trying to join tables and also SELECT things its just not working.

Thanks in advance guys. I appreciate it may be a simple solution, but it will be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write explicitly all non-aggregated columns into both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists ( *Btw, no need to use a nested query, and if it's the case `MEDICATION_ID` column is missing in it* )  :

```
SELECT I.MEDICATION_ID, M.MEDICATION_NAME, SUM(I.STOCK_LEVEL) AS STOCK_LEVEL,
       SUBSTR(M.MEDICATION_DESC,1,20) "Medication Description", M.MANUFACTURER, M.PACK_SIZE
  FROM INVENTORY I
  JOIN MEDICATION M ON M.MEDICATION_ID = I.MEDICATION_ID
 GROUP BY I.MEDICATION_ID, M.MEDICATION_NAME, SUBSTR(M.MEDICATION_DESC,1,20),
          M.MANUFACTURER, M.PACK_SIZE;
```

This way, you'll be able to return all the listed columns.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked. I had tried this previously and hadn't listed all the non-aggregated columns. I'm already looking through all the posts on here, this place is a treasure trove of information. Thanks for your help.